# Pros and cons of nesting all classes in a single public class

Tags: java, rabbitmq

So I've seen such an approach in Java

```
public class AMQP {
    public static class Connection { ... }
    public static class Channel { ... }
    ...
}
```

The pros I see.. well one possible advantage:

- the user can "partially import" the classes  by just importing `AMQP`
  and use them as e.g. `AMQP.Connection` This is a solution for avoiding full class names in Java (e.g. `com.lol.a.b.c.AMQP.Connection`) and avoiding name clashes (i.e. `Connection` is not an original name for a class)

The huge disadvantage I see is:

- everything is in one file (yes, the `AMQP.java` is ca. 2000 lines of code)

**So:**
Why would one introduce such a design?

Comment: This will kill modularity.

Answer (score 2):

Having everything in a single file is not a disadvantage per se. The disadvantage comes from reduced legibility, tight coupling and other such issues.

However, if those classes are small, it's understandable to include them as static nested classes. It's hard to say too much about the architecture based on this small snippet of code.

Comment: Well I've simply never seen such an approach (in Java), and this is used in a VERY popular messaging library (rabbit mq).. So I was thinking.. maybe there is a performance win, or sth... ?

Comment: Well it's not **that** special. People seem to have these weird notions of what's right and what's wrong. It's not like programming is an exact science. Maybe there are specific reasons behind the choice of these inner classes, or maybe not.